# How to debug `InputPort::Eval(): required InputPort[0] is not connected`

Tags: c++, drake

## Background

I am trying to simulate a double pendulum mounted on a cart. I used the `examples/multibody/cart_pole/cart_pole_simulation.cc` as a starting point.

I created a new `.sdf` based on `cart_pole.sdf` and added for my double pendulum cart.  I've verified (visually, through drake-visualizer) that the `sdf` file appears correct (changing the joint values moves the model as expected)

Due to the addition of a new joint, I added the following line to my source file (where `mid_joint` is the name of the joint between the first link of the pendulum and the second link of the pendulum.

```
  const RevoluteJoint<double>& mid_joint = tribot.GetJointByName<RevoluteJoint>("mid_joint");

  mid_joint.set_angle(&tribot_context, 0.0);
```

## Problem

My program compiles correctly, but I get the following error when I try to run my system.

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  InputPort::Eval(): required InputPort[0] (geometry_query) of System ::_::drake/multibody/MultibodyPlant@0000560ea69178f0 (MultibodyPlant<double>) is not connected
```

Any pointers on what this error is pointing to would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

(PS:: If anyone could tell me how to more formally verify an `sdf` file, that would be helpful)

## Solution (thanks to [Russ's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55075559/3177701))

Below are the changes required to fix the error

```
-    SceneGraph<double>& scene_graph = *builder.AddSystem<SceneGraph>();
+    auto pair = AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph(&builder, std::make_unique<MultibodyPlant<double>>(FLAGS_time_step));
+    MultibodyPlant<double>& plant = pair.plant;
+
+    SceneGraph<double>& scene_graph = pair.scene_graph;
```

```
-    MultibodyPlant<double>& plant =
-        *builder.AddSystem<MultibodyPlant>(FLAGS_time_step);
```

```
-    builder.Connect(
-            plant.get_geometry_poses_output_port(),
-            scene_graph.get_source_pose_port(plant.get_source_id().value()));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you're close.  The reason that your code has departed from the `examples/multibody/cart_pole/cart_pole_simulation.cc` starting point is that your `cartpole.sdf` almost certainly added some collision geometry, which was not present in the original example.  As such, your `MultibodyPlant` system needs to be connected to your `SceneGraph` object in the other direction, too... so that `MultibodyPlant` can ask geometry questions about collisions.

The simple solution is to change the few lines that create your `MultibodyPlant/SceneGraph` to look more like the example in e.g. `examples/multibody/inclined_plant/inclined_plane_run_dynamics.cc`.

I think we want to improve the experience of people that might use your workflow, and have opened https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/10874 .